# Is this a subject-verb agreement error?

Tags: verb-agreement

This has me a bit confused. At first I wanted to say begin, but then I started to think that "the evening news" could also be replaced by "it", so the correct form would be "begins".

The evening news ____ at 6:00. (begin/begins)

Which is correct? Could both options be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Though "news" is easily taken for a plural, in English it is treated as singular as in Radio: This is the latest news. English seems to cherish such anomalies of number.

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/news

Sometimes I ask myself when will English abolish that anomaly and say: Here are the news. The funny thing is in French it was a plural les nouvelles. Did German or Dutsch have an influence (Was gibt es Neues, Wat is er nieuw)?

Comment: So begins is the correct option?

Comment: @k.Lind yes it is